# Bamboo 5.5.0 - How to delete a remote agent's capability via the bamboo-capabilities.properties file?

Tags: linux, automation, continuous-integration, remote-access, bamboo

I am currently trying to automate the process of bamboo remote agent installation and uninstallation. I have run into a problem in regards to adding and removing capabilities.

**What I am trying to automate:**

(The following is what I do on the bamboo server via the GUI, I want to do this on the remote agent machine via bash script.)

1. I install the remote agent on a VM machine, then start it up. I go to the bamboo interface and click on the newly created agent's name.
2. I add a custom capability type, for the key I put 'buildserver' and for the value I put the name of the agent.
3. I add an 'Executable' capability of type 'Command' with Executable label 'cygwin' and path 'C:\cygwin64\bin\bash'
4. I navigate to the git executable, and remove it by clicking 'delete.' <--- **(the problem step)**

**what I've done.**

I have looked [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Configuring+remote+agent+capabilities+using+bamboo-capabilities.properties) and found a way to automate steps 1-3 using the following "bamboo-capabilities.properties" file:

```
buildserver="AGENTNAME"
system.builder.command.cygwin="C:\cygwin64\bin\bash"
```

However I am stuck on how I would remove the git capability (step 4.) I've tried something appending something like this to the file:

```
system.git.executable=""
```

but it does not seem to do anything. Does anyone know how I would do this? There seems to be very little documentation about this online.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I never found a way to get around this, but I found a workaround. I later learned the point of removing git in my situation was to allow a shared capability that was also called git to take precedence. My workaround was to set the non-shared capability to the value of the shared capability. I am not 100% sure that this does the same thing, and I am not in a position to test it yet, but as a capability seems to be only a key-value pair I don't see why it wouldn't.... will update if anything breaks.